# Need a counter based on how many people clicked on the button for the event in my website

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

We are running one event, I want to show a button in my website to check how many are interested in that event. If the user click the button he will redirected to another page and shows the number of persons clicked (counter value) in that page. the counter inrement value should be stored for nearly 3 months.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['capnum'] = ((isset($_SESSION['capnum'])) ? $_SESSION['capnum'] : 0);
if(isset($_GET['add'])){
     $_SESSION['capnum']++;
}
?>
<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="add" />
</form>

<?php echo $_SESSION['capnum']; ?>
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: First off, as @Ali786 says, what have you tried. What are you thoughts about what if the same person click twice? Where do you want to store the click Count?

Comment: @Ali786 I tried this but not giving appropriate results.

Comment: You need to use a server side data store, such as mySQL. The Session is per-user, and will not last 3 months.

Answer (score 0):

DB Structure:

Table:

1. Event(Columns: EventId, EventName)
2. User(Columns: UserID with all user details)
3. Tracking(Columns:EventId, UserID, date)

Process Flow:

1. When any user click on the event, its entry gets inserted in the table Tracking,
2. When another new user click on the event, we will show the existing unique count of an event from the table.